# Combining a Class selector with an ID

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I use the following css:

```
/* style.css */
#someId {
   background-color: red;
}
#someId.medium {
   width: 300px;
}
#someId.large {
   width: 500px;
}
```

with the html:

```
<!-- medium.html -->
<div id="someId" class="medium">hello, world</div>
```

and

```
<!-- large.html -->
<div id="someId" class="large">hello, world</div>
```

I know the above works fine on FireFox and Opera, and, it does *not* work on IE6 (surprise, surprise).

**My questions are:**

Is the above CSS correct according to the CSS-specifications (and where can I find this specific issue)?

What browsers (on what platform) do & do not support this?

**Update:**
The IDs are unique per page. I tried to communicate that by having `medium.html` and `large.html` but apparently it wasn't obvious enough.

**Update 2:**
The code example above was just written to illustrate my question. It is not part of production code and it is not meant to be complete. In short, it is just an example to demonstrate a problem with a very specific solution.

Comment: hmm about those duplicate id attributes..

Comment: The IDs are unique per document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) have a table of which selector (among other things) browser supports. unfortunaltly, there is not test for combining selector.
but as ie6 fail [multiple classes](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multipleclasses.html) it's not that surprising.

[w3c css specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) explains how css selector should works, there is a `DIV.warning`and `E#myid` which are not exactly like yours but suggest it should work (maybe it's explain in the page I didn't read it all ;) )

Comment: IE6 fails mltiple classes? Lame.

Comment: Lame it may be, it is still a requirement for me to get it working in IE6

Answer (score 2):

if you do not need "#someId" to be an id you can make it to a class ".someId" and then use the other two classes to extend where needed... like this class="someId medium" ect. Try this and see if it will work. Besides it`s a better solution anyway because you can not have two ids with the same name on one page.

```
.someId {
   background-color: red;
}
.medium {
   width: 300px;
}
.large {
   width: 500px;
}
```

and then..

```
<div class="someId medium">hello, world</div>
```

or

```
<div class="someId large">hello, world</div>
```

Comment: Since IE6 does not support multiple classes, your solution makes no difference from the original. but I need the Id anyhow. Also, the Id is unique per document.

Comment: ok i tried... :(
Anyway you still can`t have more then one unique id on the same page. 
And are you sure about this thing with multiole classes? because i use this method when writing css and it always worked for me. For testing im using IETester...

Comment: IE 6 supports multiple classes in HTML. What it doesn’t support properly is the multiple class *selector* in CSS. So `class="someId medium"` works, but to IE 6, `.someId.medium` and `.medium` are the same selector.

Answer (score 1):

Should be working! That's odd. Try flipping them over, as in `.large#someId`.

Comment: Should be working? where? in what browser on what platform? please be more specific.

Comment: Should be working everywhere, that's a pretty basic selector, it's not even a pseudo-thingy.

Comment: Welcome to cross browser development :(

Answer (score 1):

Crikey. I’ve never come across this one before, but you’re totally right. Your code should work as you’re expecting.

I’m pretty sure it’s only IE 6 that’ll have a problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is being more verbose than you would like to be. Add to the class names like so:

```
<div id="someId" class="someId-medium">hello, world</div>
```

or

```
<div id="someId" class="someId-large">hello, world</div>
```

and then change your CSS to this:

```
#someId {
    background-color: red;
}
.someId-medium {
    width: 300px;
}
.someId-large {
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree; it's not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Like some mentioned above, ID a unique identifier, thus should only be used once in a page. Normally, ID's would be used for major sections in your mark-up like #header, #content #footer, etc... for the rest, just use classes.

As for your text, change the #someId to .someId and then you can use .large or .medium since you can apply multiple classes to an element.

```
<div class="someId large">hello, world</div>
```

And your CSS would be

```
.someId { background-color: #ccc; }
.large { font-size: 50px; }
.medium { font-size: 25px; }
```

Also... if the text "Hello, World" is a title, I strongly suggest you use the proper elements (h1, h2, etc...) and tweak their styles rather than create new ones.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: For the comment below, here's a little HTML code that I've just tested out in IE6 and works. It works in FF and Opera as well so I'm assuming it works in Safari and Chrome too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>An XHTML 1.0 Strict standard template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .something { background-color: #ccc; }
    .else { color: #090; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="something">This is just something</div>
    <div class="else">This is just else</div>
    <div class="something else">This is something else</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is about cross-browser feature support in combination with the specification.

Comment: Multiple classes works, even in IE6. See edited response above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if dragging a Javascript library into the mix is possible in your application, but a lot of CSS that doesn't work well in IE6 is possible when using jQuery.

However, if you have no other use for a the 24kb jQuery library, it seems a hefty addon for a single CSS-attribute. Maybe you can go with graceful degradation?

Comment: Using javascript to solve a CSS issue would mix scripting and layout. So this option is out. There are other options to fix this; If it is only IE6 we will write fix it in a separate stylesheet.