# Browser support for the combined type, ID and class selectors?

Tags: css, browser, css-selectors

A *type selector* matches the name of a document language element type. A type selector matches every instance of the element type in the document tree. For example:

```css
/* The following rule matches all H1 elements 
   in the document tree:  */
h1 { font-family: sans-serif; }
```

An *ID selector* matches an element instance based on its unique identifier.

```css
/* The following rule matches the element whose 
   ID attribute has the value "header":  */
#header { text-align: center; }
```

A *class selector* matches

```css
/* The following rule matches all elements 
   with class "money":  */
.money { color: green; }
```

Selectors can be combined in CSS:

```css
h1#chapter1 { font-size: 32px; text-align: center }

p#chapter1.intro { text-align: left }

p.ending { font-style: italic; }

#login.disabled { color: #f00; }
```

My question is, what is browser support (IE6 and up) for the combined type, ID, and class selector?

Comment: Note that - assuming your HTML is valid - there's almost certainly no point in combining id with either of the others (and doing so will slow down rendering); you can only have one element with a given id. I could just about see an argument for #id.class, if you're applying CSS to several different pages, I guess.

Comment: @Chowlett -- there is actually a very common use case for combining an id with a class -- when you're using similar templates for different pages (commonly with a CMS, but could be a static site too). If you have two page layouts that differ only slightly, it helps to keep the CSS clean by just adding a class here or there, instead of changing all the id's (or worse, adding another non-semantic wrapper div around everything so you can get another id in there).

Comment: @Jordan - yep, fair enough. I guess I was meaning that there's little point having `#id` as a _child_ of another selector.

Answer (score 3):

All your given selector combinations are supported in every browser in modern-day use. Including IE6+.

The only thing IE6 has trouble parsing is combined class selectors:

```
.class1.class2
```

which it reads as whichever class comes last in the chain (`.class2` in this case), thereby causing it to match any element with at least that last class. An illustration can be found in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772305/106224).

Comment: +1. As @BoltClock says, everything you asked for will work in IE6. But despite that, I'd still strongly recommend dropping support for IE6 -- it's usage has virtually dropped off completely in the last 12 months.

Comment: @Spudley -- I think it's unprofessional to make that recommendation without having any understanding of the context. You don't know who his clients are, who the client's users are, what countries they're in, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to this question:
[Combining a Class selector with an ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333373/css-combining-a-class-selector-with-an-id)

...seem to indicate that #id.class does NOT work in IE6

Comment: That's strange. I remember trying it before and seeing it work. Let me make a new test case and see.