# CSS selector browser compatibility of #idValue.classValue Selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, cross-browser

How would I go about looking up or comprehensively testing the browser compatibility of a particular CSS selector?

The selector in question has this form:

```
#idValue.classValue
```

Which will find an element with id `idValue` with a class of `classValue` - so, like this thing:

```
<div id="idValue" class="classValue">
```

How compatible is this with the major browsers? How would I research the compatibility of this selector without running all the browsers? Is there a name for this kind of compound selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every browser supports this selector fully. There is no special name for it, although it's interesting to note that it *is* called a "compound selector", as it's a combination of two simple selectors.

If you flip the selector around, it should work just as well:

```
.classValue#idValue
```

See also:

- [Browser support for the combined type, ID and class selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141598/browser-support-for-the-combined-type-id-and-class-selectors)
- [Combining a Class selector with an ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333373/combining-a-class-selector-with-an-id)

As for researching browser support, [QuirksMode.org's CSS compatibility table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) is a good resource, although it doesn't mention every available selector. [l–c–n.com has a much more comprehensive table.](http://dev.l-c-n.com/CSS3-selectors/browser-support.php)

Comment: So, no compatibility warnings? How about versions of IE going backward? At what point does it disappear if I go back in time through the various versions of IE?

Comment: @artlung: I suspect every version does, but then again it wasn't until IE4 that I started using a web browser (IE3 was the first version to support CSS).

Comment: IE up to and including version 6 does have trouble with chained class selectors - see my edit.

Comment: so you're saying a CSS selector like: `.className1.className2` would cause problems with IE6 or before. I've been around longer than you, but I don't remember using CSS in this way at that time. (I suffered from severe classitis and did not use the cascade well). Regardless, thanks.