# Is using id.class cross browser compatible in CSS?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

When writing CSS selectors is it safe to use id.class? For example:

```
<div id="foo" class="bar"></div>

#foo.bar { border: 1px solid #000; }
```

Which browsers will this not be supported on?

Comment: It should be supported cross-browser, but why would you do that? ID's are supposed to be unique in a webpage...

Comment: @josh.trow It's useful for doing stuff like `#foo.active` and `#foo.selected` and similar stuff.

Comment: @peirix pretty much why I need to do it. My ids are unique on a page.

Comment: Here this question was already discessed:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333373/combining-a-class-selector-with-an-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you use it, it may trigger [a bug](http://jan.moesen.nu/code/html-css/ie-id-class-combo-bug/) on IE6.

Comment: I don't care about ie6 but glad to see that's the only one that has an issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser will support that (although it may be unnecessary since the ID uniquely identifies that element anyway).

Comment: I can see at least 2 reasons one might do this: adding classes with javascript/jQuery, and wanting to 'tweak' a particular class style when applied to a particular div (eg when applying .highlight to #main, set `background` to a different `color`).